# Transferring files over a network: Send from client or from server?

Tags: sockets, client, server, file-transfer

I am presently working on a client-server solution to transfer files to another machine via a socket network connection. I am fairly new to the whole client-server thing and therefore have the following - admittedly very basic - question:

For the file transfer, does it make any difference if I am sending the file from a client to a server or from a server to a client?

Any qualified insight into this will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For the file transfer, does it make any difference if I am sending the file from a client to a server or from a server to a client?

Basically, no it does not matter. Once you have the connection made you are free to send data in both directions. Although you have to consider that a server won't accept data that is sent to it unless it explicitly reads from the socket.

To be a bit more general, server and client are completely arbitrary for a home brewed implementation of data transfer. If you boil this down to the simplest concept then you are just opening a socket and writing data to it on one side, and on the other side you are reading from a different socket.

You might choose to implement a single client program capable of connecting other clients (P2P) and sending files back and forth. In that case you could call the "server" the program that is currently sending the file, and the "client" is the program currently receiving.

Alternatively, you could implement two programs, one for client and one for server. Your server will listen for connections and the client will decide when it wants to connect to the server.

Remember that there are network limitations for connecting. If the program that is listening for connections is behind a firewall then you have to be sure you are forwarding the correct ports. If you are connecting machines within a LAN then you probably have nothing to worry about.

Comment: Thanks, Mike! This is very helpful information and just the kind of confirmation I was looking for. Your comments are much appreciated.